# Чи є синоніми до слова "пак"?

Tags: синоніми

Як вказано у [тлумачному словнику української мови](http://sum.in.ua/s/pak) слово *пак* використовують для підсилення. Ось приклад:

> Давно пак діялось? А серце сном нечулим, Мов павутиною, устиг час оплести...

Проте слово *пак* для мене незвичайне, і я його не часто чую, тож мені цікаво чи існують синоніми до цього слова.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Мені здається, одні підсильні частки (*пак*) можна замінювати іншими підсильними частками (*аж*, *бо*, *вже*, *ж*, *же*, *і*, *й*, *навіть*, *но*, *та*, *таки*), хоча якими саме — залежить від контексту:

- > Давно **пак** діялось?
  >   Давно **ж бо** те діялось?
- > — А то — дивись **пак**: хотів мене зв'язати!
  >    — А то — дивись **же**: хотів мене зв'язати!
- > Оце **пак** лихо!
  >   Оце-**то** лихо!
- > Якби **пак** у мене такий язик та така вдача, як у Солов'їхи, я б дала собі ради.
  >   Якби-**но** мені такий язик та таку вдачу, як у Солов'їхи, я б дала собі ради.
- > Чи то **пак** не ваше порося ходило по майдані?
  >   Чи то **й** не ваше порося ходило по майдані?

(Примітка: я не вдивлявся глибоко в контекст наведених фраз (далі, власне, фраз — не перечитивув самі твори, звідки їх узято), можливо, при ретельнішому підході такі заміни виявляться не найкращими — але сама ідея того, що одні підсилювальні частки в певних випадках можна замінити на інші підсилювальні частки, видається вірогідною.)

Answer (score 4):

Приклади синонімів із **[Словника синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA)**  для визначення  **[3,4,5](http://sum.in.ua/s/pak)** слова ***"пак"***

> **МА́БУ́ТЬ** *вст. сл.* (уживається для вираження невпевненості в тому, про що говориться в реченні), **ЛИБО́НЬ, ПЕ́ВНО [ПЕ́ВНЕ],
>   НАПЕ́ВНО [НАПЕ́ВНЕ], ДОПЕ́ВНЕ, ОЧЕВИ́ДНО, ВИ́ДНО, ВИ́ДКО,
>   ОЧЕВИ́ДЯЧКИ** *розм.*, **ОЧЕВИ́ДЬКИ** *розм.*, **ПРО́БІ** *розм.*,
>   **ПАК** *розм.*, **ПА́КИ** *розм.*, **ВІ́ДАЙ** *розм.*, **АЧЕ́Й** **розм.**, **МА́БУ́ТИ** *заст.*, **МА́БІ́ТЬ** *діал.*, **МАЙ** *діал.*, **БЕ́ЗМАЛЬ** *діал.*; **НАДІ́СЬ [НАДІ́ЙСЬ]** *розм.* (з відтінком вірогідності); **МО́ЖЕ, МОЖЛИ́ВО, МО’** *діал.*,
>   **ПРАВДОПОДІ́БНО** *діал.* (уживається для вираження припущення).
>   **ПРОТЕ́** (незважаючи на щось), **ОДНА́К, ОДНА́ЧЕ, ВСЕ Ж[УСЕ́ Ж], ВСЕ́-ТАКИ [УСЕ́-ТАКИ], ВТІМ, А ВТІМ [УТІ́М], ПАК [ПА́КИ]** *розм.*,
>   **ПРЕ́ЦІНЬ** *діал.*

Comment: Здається, запитувача цікавили синоніми саме в першому (підсильному) значенні. Але все одно дякую.